# 7zip is zipping the source path / empty variable

Tags: powershell, file, logging, zip, 7zip

I made a powershell script which is checking different folders for log files older then x days in a variable `$toBeZipped`.

The script is working fine as long as there are files and the variable is not empty.
If the variable is empty, because there are no files matching the filter, 7zip is zipping the folder where the 7z.exe is located

How can I fix this?

This is the command:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" A -t7z $zipFile $toBeZipped -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -aoa
```

Comment: so ... test the $Var to see if there is anything in it?

Comment: What do you mean? I tested it, it's empty. Thats the problem. It's the same behaviour when running the command without the $var

Comment: perhaps u cud add an if statement where you check for the variable is empty or not. if not empty process else do nothing

Comment: @mikejohnsen - test before you use it ... if it is empty, DO NOT run the command at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use an "if statement" to check if `$toBeZipped` is empty. Anything like this:

```
if($toBeZipped -ne $null) {
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" A -t7z $zipFile $toBeZipped -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -aoa
} else {
Write-Host "toBeZipped is empty"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Made it work with checking if the var is empty.

I used the following if statement

```
IF([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Files)) {
Write-Host "Given string is NULL or EMPTY"
Continue
} else {
#Zip commmand
}
```